# How to resolve Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found! exception?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know there is lot of answers for the above issue with small difference 'directive' instead of ngChange. I am using 1.7.2 version. 
Here is my code

```
<select class="full-width" id="searchWithSavedFilter" ng-modal="searchWithSavedFilter" ng-change="test(searchWithSavedFilter)">
 <option ng-repeat="p in SavedFilters" value="{{p.Id}}">{{p.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

and the angularjs reference code is

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you need **`ng-model`** instead of **`ng-modal`**

```
<select class="full-width" id="searchWithSavedFilter" ng-model="searchWithSavedFilter" ng-change="test(searchWithSavedFilter)">
```

Comment: Thanks.. My mistake.. :)